# TCL code that can encrypt and decrypt a string

Tags: encryption, tcl

I need a piece of code that defines functions which can encrypt and decrypt a piece of string. What I basically want is that the string should not be visible to third-party users, so that when the string originates in one file, it is converted to, say, an integer value using the encrypt function and then it is passed as parameter to another file. There the decrpyt function then decrypts it back and uses the string to perform actions on it.

Any suggestions or already available codes will be just fine!

Please help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install [tcllib](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net). There are several standard encryption algorithms implemented in tcllib.

The following encryption algorithms are available:

- blowfish: http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/blowfish.html
- aes: http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/aes.html
- des (including triple des): http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/des.html
- rc4: http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/rc4.html

Comment: For simple obfuscation, there's yencode http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/yencode.html

Answer (score 2):

The [des package in Tcllib](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/des.html) should do what you want. It's pretty easy to use:

```
package require des

set key "12345678";  # Must be 8 bytes long
set msg "abcde"

##### ENCRYPTION
set encryptedMsg [DES::des -dir encrypt -key $key $msg]
# $encryptedMsg is a bunch of bytes; you'll want to send this around...

##### DECRYPTION
set decryptedMsg [DES::des -dir decrypt -key $key $encryptedMsg]
puts "I got '$decryptedMsg'"
```

Note that DES will pad the message out to a multiple of 8 bytes long.

Answer (score 0):

Please visit the TCL/TK homepage e.g 
here:http://wiki.tcl.tk/900

That's just one way of doing it. There will be much more, I'm sure.