# Missing "des" Tcl package

Tags: tcl

When i am trying to execute the following tcl code i got this

can't find package des
while executing
"package require des"
(file "encdec.tcl" line 1)

**Tcl code**

```
package require des

set key "12345678";  # Must be 8 bytes long
set msg "abcde"

##### ENCRYPTION
set encryptedMsg [DES::des -dir encrypt -key $key $msg]
# $encryptedMsg is a bunch of bytes; you'll want to send this around...

##### DECRYPTION
set decryptedMsg [DES::des -dir decrypt -key $key $encryptedMsg]
puts "I got '$decryptedMsg'"
```

how to get that package ?

Comment: Well, it seems you posted here the example code snippet taken from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13509728/720999), and that answer tells *exactly* where to get the "des" package.

Answer (score 2):

This package is [a part](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/des.html) of "the standard Tcl library", [tcllib](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/).

If you're using a "batteries included" Tcl distribution, like ActiveTcl, you should use its means to get this package; for instance, with ActiveTcl, the command to install `tcllib` would be

```
teacup install tcllib
```

(you should run it in your Windows console prompt).

If you're using Tcl installed from a package of your operating system, `tcllib` is typically available in the form of a package as well.  For instance, on a Debian (or its derivative) the command to install `tcllib` would be

```
apt-get install tcllib
```

Next time please tell us about your platform up front, without forcing anyone here to guess.

Comment: thanks for your help, i am using ubuntu os, is i have to follow the above procedure ?